# How do I use "arbeiten an"?

Tags: word-usage

In a company flyer I just came across this formulation in a paragraph on quality management:

> **Wir arbeiten kontinuierlich an unseren Qualitätsdefiziten**

It is obvious that they meant something like *"We continuously work to overcome quality deficits"*.

Is the expression *"arbeiten an"* appropriate in this context?

Comment: This is great!

You're showing a very good example where the sentence say both: "we're working on getting better" and "we're working increasing the quaility of our deficits" ... thanks for this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Arbeiten an" is used both for things you want to [achieve](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/arbeiten+an.html):

> Er arbeitet an einem Projekt.

... and things you want to [overcome](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/an+schw%E4chen+arbeiten.html):

> Er arbeitet an seinen Defiziten.

A quick glance at [the Google results for "arbeiten an"](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22arbeiten%20an%22) indicates that the former usage is by far the most common, but both are correct.

Comment: You can even say "Sie arbeitet ständig an sich." which means "she continously works to improve herself".

Answer (score 5):

Arbeiten an is best translated as working on. So literally it is "We continuously work on our quality deficits".

Answer (score 5):

From the context it's pretty obvious what the writer means. Stylistically (and given this is taken from a *company image* brochure) though it would be better to write a clear and unambiguous sentence:

> Wir arbeiten kontinuierlich daran, unsere Qualitätsdefizite zu beseitigen.

---

<sub>Note: That company is obviously still working on their quality deficits. ;-)</sub>

Comment: +1 for the ambiguity. Maybe they're also working hard to *increase* their quality deficits... :)

Comment: "Wir arbeiten kontiernuierlich daran, unsere Qualitätsdefizite zu minimieren." - Would be more precise.

Comment: @blindfold I think you don't want to read that in a brochure.

Comment: @splattne I fully agrree on this! I don't think I want to read about quality deficits in any broschure, do you? - "minimieren" is a little less offensive than "beseitigen"